# Hot and ground shorted with breaker off, but has normal voltage after breaker on

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, grounding, troubleshooting, circuit

I swapped an old outlet and a pair of switches on the same circuit today (same breaker), and used a multimeter to check the connectivity to make sure I installed them correctly.
With the breaker off, the hot wire (black) and ground wire (bare) were connected, according to the readings with 4 ohms. The voltage between ground and hot read 0V.
I tried everything I knew then eventually gave up and turned on the breaker, and was again suprised to find the breaker didn't trip.
With the breaker on, I measured the voltage between hot and ground and it read 124V, which if the hot and ground were shorted I expected it to read 0V.
I didn't measure the resistance with the power on as it'd probably burn my multimeter.

To sum it up:

- Breaker off

  - 4ohms between hot and ground
  - 0 Volts between hot and ground
  - Hot and ground seems to be shorted.
- Breaker on

  - Same measurement position
  - 124 Volts between hot and ground
  - As a precaution I also measured the temperature of the circuit breaker and the problematic one's temperature isn't higher than the others so it doesn't seem to be actively shorting.

What's going on here is beyond me and I can't come up with a theory that explains this. Few guesses:

1. Multimeter ohmmeter is broken

   - Tried measuring some spare wire, beep. No wire, no beep, so this seems fine?
2. Somehow the hot wire is electrified even when the breaker is off, so it messes up the ohmmeter?

   - I don't really know how this works, tho measured the voltage between hot and ground is 0V. Maybe the ground is charged? No idea what I'm saying.
3. Maybe has something to do with the broken outdoor lamp post.
4. ???

Any idea what could be going on?

[image: rough circuit diagram]

Comment: A meter itself should not short/trip a breaker.  Trip of a breaker should happen if a ground wire and hot wire touch each other directly.   So ~124 volts read on a meter means you have good ground there, not a short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something with a DC resistance of 4 ohms is plugged into another outlet on the same circuit. Find that other outlet, unplug the device, turn off the breaker and your hot-to-ground resistance will become normal, i.e., infinity.

Comment: Good call .. also turn off any lights or anything else on the circuit that cannot be unplugged.

Comment: Exactly. I got confused the same way. Have to find my question....